# C: Accessing the second argv via a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, int, argv, dereference

As I'm quite new to C, there's something I don't yet get about pointers. I'd like to check wether a command line argument is integer or not, but in a separate function, so that I pass in the pointer of the argv array.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(check(argv)){
        // Do stuff to argv[1]
    }
}

int check(char* p){
    // Test wether p+1 is int
    return 1;
}
```

I have tried several things mostly resulting in weird printf's (when printing the dereferenced pointer to test the value).

```
int i = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Works just fine, of course. But as the pointer is the only thing passed to the function, I'm paralysed.

Comment: argc should be used before indexing argv

Comment: change 'int check(char *p)' to 'int check (char *p[])' or 'int check (char **p)'

Comment: The current code is invalid. And the compiler told you about it. There's no point is trying to experiment with it using the current version as a starting point.

Comment: @AnT To ask a question about a working piece of code. Hmm. Now that's a brilliant idea, innit! No, the compiler told me nothing about my various experiments. Some passed with no warnings and would not execute.

Comment: @Felix: I'm nor sure what you mean by "working". Your attempt to call `check` with `argv` argument would normally produce a diagnostic message from the compiler, either about parameter type mismatch (if `check` has a prototype) or about declaration-definition mismatch (otherwise). These diagnostic messages tell you exactly that: the code is invalid. This is what has to be fixed first.

Comment: @AnT I mean... This certainly is not the whole code. The original one includes the necessary libraries and in it, the check function preceeds the main. No error messages were shown. But thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Felix: False. "No error messages were shown" means absolutely nothing in a typical C compiler. C compilers produce feedback in form of "diagnostic messages", not "error mesages". Which means that by default, a large pile of "warning messages" issued by these compilers are actually hard and severe errors, which were simply reported as "warnings" (due to poor design of the compiler). I'm sure that's exactly what happened in your case. Your original code suffers form obvious major errors, which your compiler undoubtedly reported to you (liklely as "warnings").

Comment: But you ignored these diagnostic messages apparently because they were "just warnings". If you want to run your compiler in default mode, it implies that you will inspect every hickup, sneeze and "warning " generated by your compiler with a loupe, and provide a written report for each and every one of them on why you decided to ignore it (post full text here). If you don't wanna do it, then either learn to configure your compiler in a more pedantic mode (so that it reports errors as "errors") or simply listen what more knowledgeable people tell you here on SO. There's no other way.

Comment: It doesn't take a rocket scientist to feed your code to an online compiler and make it pinpoint the error immediately: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4ae8ce8cd81bfeb . And you are going to tell us that your compiler was completely silent about it?

Comment: @AnT I think I made myself perfectly clear when I stated "some passed with no warnings". That did include errors aswell. I am using Code::Blocks, if you want to bash a particular program. I think it uses Gnu GCC to compile. Don't assume I ignored any errors or warnings. I provided practically four lines of C code in the post above. I'm surprised how much can be said about them. But a kind gentleman below solved the problem already, and the program works since two days ago. My problem was not with syntax or compiling. It was "Accessing the second argv via a pointer". But thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argv is a two dimensional array, which is to say that argv is an array of arrays. Specifically, argv is an array of char arrays. Now, the data that argv is storing is the arguments passed from the command line to the program, with argv[0] being the actual name of the program and the rest being the arguments.

Now, to answer your question, you need to not pass argv in its entirety to the function "check". What you need to do is pass one of argvs elements. This is because the parameter to "check" is a char array, and argv is an array of char arrays. So try passing argv[1] to check the first argument.

**Edit: Try this to check all arguments except the name of the program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if( check(argv[i]) ){
            // Do stuff to argv[i]
        }
}

int check(char* p){
    int i = 0;
    char c = p[i];
    while (c != '\0') {
        if (!isdigit(c))
            return 0;
        c = p[++i];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: To make sure: for an int check(char ** p), p[1] would be the pointer to the second argv?

Comment: @Felix yes, but only if sufficient arguments have actually been passed

Comment: @Alnitak Yep, that's not a problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
int check(char* p){
```

The above function expects a pointer to a `char` while you are passing `argv` which is array of `char *`
Try

```
int check(char* p[]){
```

Also before using `argv[1]` check if `argv[1]` exists ie check `argc`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
if(argc>1 && check(argv)){
    // Do stuff to argv[1]
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before indexing an array of pointer, we have to be sure it's valid. We have to use `argc` to this purpose.

[strtol](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/strtol.3.html) is a function which parse a string and detect error if it's not of the base asked.

Ty this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(check(argc, argv)){
        // Do stuff to argv[1]
    }
}

int check( int argc, char * argv[] ){
    if( argc > 1 ) {
       char * err = NULL;
       strtol( argv[1], &err, 10 );
       return argv[1][0] != '\0' && *err != '\0';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: NB: the final pointer in the `argv[]` array is guaranteed to be `NULL`, so you don't _strictly_ have to check `argc` first.

Comment: Have you a good, normative source for that or is it a usage, a convention?

Comment: I don't have a source myself, but there's plenty other answers here on SO that assert that the standards do require this.