# char * argv[] is an array of pointers or array of char strings

Tags: c, argv

From my understanding so far, 
`char * argv[] = {"abc", "def"};`
initialises an array of 2 `char` pointers. First one points to `"abc"`, the second to `"def"`. And the name `argv` is also a pointer that points to the first pointer in the array `argv`.

Why does some say `argv` is an array of `char` strings then? (like in the C Programming Language by K&R). Don't they mean an array of pointers to `char`s, which the book also explains.

If my hypothesis is correct, the `%s` in `printf("%s", argv[1])` is not expecting a `char string` at all, rather, a pointer to the `char string`?

Thanks for your patience!

Stuff i've read:

[Pointer to Pointer with argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631282/pointer-to-pointer-with-argv)

[C: Accessing the second argv via a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143007/c-accessing-the-second-argv-via-a-pointer)

Comment: In C, a string is a "pointer to char", aka `char *`. I think you've invented two concepts where only one exists.

Comment: In C a string is a zero-terminated array of characters. As all other arrays it commonly decays to a pointer to its first element (of type `char *`). All functions handling strings expect such a decayed pointer of type `char *` (or possible `const char *`).

Comment: Oh that makes sense.Guess I confused it with a string in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As used in the C standard, “A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character” (C 2018 7.1.1 1). It is not a `char *`. A `char *` may point to the first character of a string and is sometimes referred to in the C standard as a pointer to a string, but this is sloppy terminology as a `char *` is necessarily a pointer to a character—there is no technical definition for what it means to point to a “sequence,” although we may take it to mean to point to the first element of a sequence.

> From my understanding so far, `char * argv[] = {"abc", "def"};` initialises an array of 2 `char` pointers.

That is correct.

> And the name `argv` is also a pointer that points to the first pointer in the array `argv`.

That is not correct given the definition of `argv` in the question. The definition `char * argv[] = {"abc", "def"};` defines `argv` to be an array of `char *`. It is not a pointer.

When an array is used as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it is operated on as an array. (Also, when an array is initialized with a string literal, the string literal is used as an array.) Other than these circumstances, when an array is used in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to its first element. This conversion is automatic and is so common that students may mistake the array, or the name of the array, for the pointer it is converted to. That is a mistake. The array is not a pointer.

> Why does some say `argv` is an array of `char` strings then? (like in the C Programming Language by K&R).

Kernighan and Ritchie do not say this in either edition of *The C Programming Language* in any of the places listed for `argv` in the index. In the first edition, 1978, they say on page 110 “the second (`argv`) is a pointer to an array of character strings that contain the arguments, one per string.” In the second edition, 1988, they say on page 114 “the second (`argv`, for argument vector) is a pointer to an array of character strings that contain the arguments, one per string.” The index also lists page 163 for `argv`, but there is just an incidental mention there, referring to `argv[0]` for the program name.

Note that they refer to `argv` as a pointer rather than an array. This is because the `argv` parameter to `main` is a pointer. Although it may be declared with `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, a parameter that is declared as an array is automatically adjusted to be a pointer. Thus `char *argv[]` in the declaration of `main` defines `argv` to be something different from the statement you showed, `char * argv[] = {"abc", "def"};`. In the parameter declaration, it is automatically adjusted to be a pointer. In the separate definition, it is an array.

Although Kernighan and Ritchie do refer to `argv` as a pointer, not an array as you wrote, they says it is a “pointer to an array.” This is also sloppy terminology. Its type is pointer-to-pointer-to-`char`, not pointer-to-array-of-`char`. It is a pointer to an array only in the sense that it is a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`.

> If my hypothesis is correct, the `%s` in `printf("%s", argv[1])` is not expecting a `char string` at all, rather, a pointer to the `char string`?

Per C 2018 7.21.6.1 8, for an `s` specifier to `printf` without a modifier or a precision, “the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type. Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating null character.” Thus, one should pass a `char *` (or a `signed char *` or `unsigned char *`) that points to the initial character of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Char **argv points to an argument, and a character in that argument.

Example:

```
/* ************************************************************************** */
/*                                                                            */
/*                                                        :::      ::::::::   */
/*   temp.c                                             :+:      :+:    :+:   */
/*                                                    +:+ +:+         +:+     */
/*   By: albarret <marvin@42.fr>                    +#+  +:+       +#+        */
/*                                                +#+#+#+#+#+   +#+           */
/*   Created: 2019/07/05 20:14:37 by albarret          #+#    #+#             */
/*   Updated: 2019/07/05 20:17:41 by albarret         ###   ########.fr       */
/*                                                                            */
/* ************************************************************************** */

#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        return (0);
    }
    while (argv[1][i])
    {
        ft_putchar(argv[1][i]);
        i++;
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
}
```